# Navigation menu using jQuery/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I build the following navigation menu using jQuery/JSON only ?
[image]

My JSON is as follows;

```
{
   "general":{
      "logo":"assets/images/logo.png",
      "name" : "Company Name"
   },
   "navigation":[
      {
         "title":"Home",
         "link":"index.html"
      },
      {
         "title":"Products",
         "link":"product.html",
         "subnav":[
            {
               "title":"Webapps",
               "link":"products/w.html"
            },
            {
               "title":"Mobile Apps",
               "link":"products/m.html"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would avoid anything other than jQuery.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Accessing the values in your data structure? Creating the DOM? Creating the proper CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your problem is just traversing the json..this may help.

```
for (i in jar.navigation) {
                alert(jar.navigation[i].title);
                var hassub = (jar.navigation[i].subnav != null);                
                if (hassub) {                                        
                    for (j in jar.navigation[i].subnav) {
                        alert(jar.navigation[i].subnav[j].title);
                    }}
            }
```